# correct format for Input string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, helper

I have a helper method as follows.

```
@helper DisplayTrendIndicator(double lastYear, double twoYearsAgo)
{
if (lastYear > twoYearsAgo)
{
  <img id="green" src="@VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/images/up.png")" />
}
else
{
  <img id="red" src="@VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/images/down.png")" />
}
}
```

When I try to invoke the method in my program, I get an "Input string was not in a correct format". This is how I call the above helper

`@Helpers.DisplayTrendIndicator(double.parse(lastYear.Content), double.parse(twoYearsAgo.Content))`

Note: lastYear and twoYears ago are variables returned from an API call.
I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC Project C#. How do I prevent this error from popping up.

Comment: Couldn't this be in your model to avoid confusing use of `@` in razor? You could have it in your model and call it like `@Model.DisplayTrendIndicator`

Comment: The problem is with one of the `double.Parse` calls and the string that you are passing is not in the format of a `double`.

Comment: What are the values of: lastYear.Content and twoYearsAgo.Content?

Comment: Check it "lastYear.Content" and "twoYearsAgo.Content".

Comment: Lastyear.Content and twoyearsago.Content are strings

Answer (score 1):

what are the values of lastYear and twoYears ago are variables returned from an API call.those are string??

try with `Convert.ToDouble()`